# Locking size of character to that of another character?

Tags: fontsize

I have a command for setbuilder notation,

`\newcommand{\set}[2]{\left\{ #1 \ \big| \ #2 \right\}}`

Pretty simple stuff. I have issues, however, when I want larger characters in the set, for example summations, fractions, and whatnot as the vertical bar doesn't scale. Is there a way its height can be tied to the outside brackets?

Comment: See the mathtools package and its documentation for `\DeclareMathDelimiter`. Note that it is never recommended to auto scale by default as it more often than not ends up in the wrong scale. The manual has an example that defines a one arg `\Set` macro.

Answer (score 2):

You might do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\set}[2]{\left\{ {#1}\vphantom{\big|} \;\middle|\; #2 \right\}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\set{x\in A}{x^{-1}=x^2} \\
\set{x\in A}{\frac{1}{x}=x^2}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\vphantom{\big|}` is meant to use at least `\big` size.

However, you should take into account that `\left` and `\right` will in most cases choose too big a size. The documentation of `mathtools` shows alternative approaches.

Answer (score 2):

The TeX primitive `\middle` is here just for these cases. It was introduced in eTeX extension of TeX (sometime in the nineties). Its argument is an extensible parenthesis/fence like arguments of `\left` and `\right` primitives. It can be used only somewhere inside the group given by `\left...\right` and it gets the same size.

Your macro can be defined as

```
 \def\set#1#2{\left\{ #1 \vbox to.85em{} \;\middle|\; #2  \right\}}
```

the `\vbox to.85em{}` is a strut which is equal to `\big` size.